# How do i extract column from multiple files?

Tags: shell

I have 176 text files and their names are like this from mm1,mm2,mm3 to mm176.How I will extract column 2 from those files and write all columns in an another text file?

Comment: can you pls show your effort?

Comment: Actually I am able to do this job for a single text file using awk '{print $2}' txt file name> output.txt in command line. But I want to do this for all my 176 file.

Comment: why dont you use a loop?

Comment: I tried but it was not working.

Comment: that's what you need to show here...

Comment: #!/bin/csh 
foreach rid (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 .....176)
awk '{print $2}' mm$rid.txt> output.txt

Comment: please make an edit to your question to add this stuff there. I am sorry but nobody @SO has so much time to guide for these tiny things to newcomers. Please read the rules before you post.

Comment: is `awk '{print $2}' mm*.txt> output.txt` ok? it will give you a new file with a big column. :-)